# Read Ini file in different function at the same time Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to read and use the same Ini file opened with QSettings in two différents function at the same time ?

Thank you

Comment: From Qt docs: "QSettings is reentrant. This means that you can use distinct QSettings object in different threads simultaneously. This guarantee stands even when the QSettings objects refer to the same files on disk (or to the same entries in the system registry). If a setting is modified through one QSettings object, the change will immediately be visible in any other QSettings objects that operate on the same location and that live in the same process.". So, I guess, the answer on your question is: "Yes, its possible".

Comment: Ok thank you very much